# Two intercepts for zero-truncated negative binomial model using VGAM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, quasi-likelihood, truncated-distributions

I am trying to understand the first and second intercept for the zero-truncated negative binomial regression model I estimated using VGAM. Below is my syntax:

```r
mod.negb <- vglm(ED_Visit ~ Male + Age + 
     chronic + Non_White + Depressive_Sx + 
     ACEs + Resilience + Social_Needs, 
     family = posnegbinomial(), 
     data = corr_data, trace=T)
```

And here are my coefficients for the two intercepts:

```r
coef(m2.negb)

(Intercept):1   (Intercept):2         
  -0.63701465   -0.02417784
```

Can anyone explain what intercepts 1 and 2 represent? I read somewhere that intercept 2 is a dispersion parameter, but when I run the model in other Softwares, there should be overdispersion in the data (not underdispersion).

Comment: Correct: intercept 1 is the model intercept, intercept 2 the "other distributional parameter", e.g. the standard deviation in the normal or the dispersion in your case. In the summary of your model, vglm indicates which link function is used. For Intercept 2, the dispersion parameter of the negative binomial, this is the log. Hence, your actual estimate for the dispersion parameter is exp(-0.02418) = approx. 0. Seems you have plenty of 0s in your response.

Comment: @Carsten Thank you for your response. My data has no zeros in the response variable (1 is the minimum value and max is 16). Also when I run a similar model in Mplus, the dispersion parameter is > 2, and the coefficient for all model covariates are the same. I am wondering If I am specifying my zero-truncated model incorrectly using VGAM, which is contributing to an incorrect dispersion parameter.